# Google Play Music Local Playlist

Tags: google-play-music

I have a folder on my SD Card filled with music. Would I be able to create a playlist with songs *just* from that folder? Right now those files are becoming meshed with the other songs I have already downloaded. I want to make a playlist automatically instead of manually adding each one.

Comment: Not an answer for Google Play, but I believe [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) can do this.